# Is it possible to make separate bundle for vendor libs without specifying them in require/external?

Tags: browserify

I know how to make two separate bundles (app.js/vendor.js for example) using `require` and `external` options. However when using this method I have to know the list of all modules from package.json that my app will be using. I could just require `package.json` and parse it to have a lit of vendor modules, but my package.json also requires some other libraries that are not used by my client app.

When I require a module from inside of my app I either require global dependency like this `require('gobal-dependency')` and local dependency like this `require('./local-dependency')` (with relative path). So, in fact, I want to bundle all global dependencies into vendor.js and other files into app.js.

I it possible to force browserify to put all modules required without relative path into `vendor.js`? Of course browserify would have to know that global dependency may require local dependency from inside (should also be bundled to vendor.js).

Comment: I think, there is no way to do exactly what you want with browserify commands. But you could use `no-bundle-external` instead of many `external`s to bundle your main app without global packages.

Comment: Haha, this is silly - if there is a fla `--no-bundle-external` then why there isnt flag `--bundle-external-only`? If browserify knows which requires are external then it is capable to bundle externals only I guess...

Comment: i know. i think the same. i would like to use it too in my project. i do not know why there is not such a flag.

Comment: let me know if you have found a solution... ;-)

Comment: I've posted issue here https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1313